# PHP PDO - update same value returns 0 in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the same value in DB, 
But the database returns 0 when I do that.
is it possible to return 1 or true? or force the DB update?

```
$sth =$pdo->prepeare("UPDATE table set x = :x where id=:id") 
$sth->execute()
$result = $sth->rowCount()   // that return 0;
```

x is the same value in DB and the result is 0 but i want to let the user to approve the form even with the same value

Answer (score 2):

Updating with same values will always return `false`. You need to add some some distinct value that could be updated .

For example you can have field that stores timestamp (like `updatedOn`) so every time you pass same values for rest of field, it will be accepted as time stamp field will have unique value.

Comment: good idea  thanks, the current_timestamp will return true? or should I send date from php ?

Comment: you can send date from PHP

Answer (score -4):

basically you will need to add a `WHERE` clause as you said you need to update some values

```
$sth =$pdo->prepeare("UPDATE table set x = :x where y = :y")
```

Comment: the question code is also correct in the sence that it will going to update `x` column all rows  in the table(https://teamtreehouse.com/library/modifying-data-with-sql/updating-data-in-a-database/-updating-all-rows-in-a-table)